# net472 project no longer builds using MSBuild after migrating packages.config to PackageReference

Tags: asp.net-core, msbuild, visual-studio-2017, nuget, xunit

I have a net472 project containing unit tests using xUnit, which I develop in VS 2017. The project contains tests for an ASP.NET Core project.

I have migrated its `packages.config` to the `PackageReference` style using Visual Studio. It still builds in VS after migration, but building using MSBuild was broken. I get the following error:

```
Project "<solution-file-path>.sln" (2) is building "<project-file-path>.csproj" (14) on node 1 (default targets).
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\NuGet\15.0\Microsoft.NuGet.targets(186,5): error : Your project file doesn't list 'win-x64' as a "RuntimeIdentifier". You should add 'win-x64' to the "RuntimeIdentifiers" property in your project file and then re-run NuGet restore. [<project-file-path>.csproj]
Done Building Project "<project-file-path>.csproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
```

Anyone has a hint what the reason could be?

Comment: You have a `net472` project to test (and of course reference to) the `core` project? How can he compile at all?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Edit you project file and add the following property after `<TragetFrameworkVersion>`:

```
<RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
```

That should solve the issue.

Answer (score 5):

I case others get by: I had the same issue on Azure DevOps Build jobs and I had to add:

```xml
<RuntimeIdentifier>win</RuntimeIdentifier>
```

after `<TargetFrameworkVersion>` in the .csproj.